# Elastic Search - Re boot index after updating synonym config file

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

I am using a synonym text file to define synonyms for my search index.
If I update this file, I have to stop and start the windows service before the new additions take effect..

Is there a way I can cause my index to be refreshed dynamically?
I am using NEST, but can of course make direct HTTP request to my index end point if needed.

Comment: Did you try to close and open index?

Comment: nope, I didn't try that, will give that a go now (I am pretty new to Elastic Search)

Comment: yep, that's it, thanks! feel free to add as answer so I can make it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. close index `client.CloseIndex(indexName);`
2. make changes
3. Open index `client.OpenIndex(indexName);`

I belive this should work.

Hope it helps.